# nginx access log file has incomplete request url

Tags: logging, nginx

I have a very strange problem in nginx request,

my upstream config is:

```
upstream alipay {
    server pay1:8084 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=60s;
    keepalive 32;
}
```

and the location config is:

```
    location /alipay {
        proxy_pass http://alipay;
    }
```

the correct request is something like this: http://xxxx.com/alipay/xxx/xxx

but in the nginx access log file, there is some request that miss the URI part, that is: "GET /alipay/ HTTP/1.1" 200 57 " that lead to the invalid page. And some of the request url in log is correct and response page is ok.
What is the problem here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When your clients request `http://xxxx.com/alipay/` what should happen?

Comment: When request to http://xxxx.com/alipay/ , the response is the upstream server's default index.jsp, that is can not happen because the link in the page is like: /alipay/aaa or /alipay/bbb , there is no /alipay link at all.

Comment: So your logfile has `GET /alipay/` - unless `nginx` has some `rewrite` directives that you have not shown, it must be arriving externally.

Comment: The only one rewrite in nginx.conf is :   server {
        listen 80 default;
        server_name _;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://myhostname.com permanent;
    }